# My edit shown as proposed edit after review when I look at review result

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I rejected a review as too minor. A tag was removed, but other problems remained with the post.

After I got to "no items", I happened to look at the Stats, to see who was reviewing as well (just after midnight, so easy to tell, and there are some people that I like to see are reviewing at the same time), and noticed I'd only done two reviews. I thought I'd done three.

So I used the back-arrow on the browser. Before I got through the items I'd reviewed, I noticed that the "too minor" post in question had been Accepted. So I went off to Edit.

I then started back-arrowing again and arrived back at the Review:

[image]

The circly bits are the changes I made (the square is a decision I bottled out of, not knowing how mv might be pronounced in that context). The tag change was from the original proposer, as is the comment.

[Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3473551).

On the revision history, everything looks fine and normal. The latest two edits (amazingly my edit was the sixth to be made to the post) are there and correct. I have tried Refreshing, it makes no difference. I've waited a while, and it remains unchanged, so I don't think it is caching.

For anyone looking at the results of that review, I look a bit of a fool - why did I reject it? someone might wonder. This must be happening to other people, and is going to making tracking things through the review more complex, although full knowledge can be gained by looking at the revision history of the post.

I can reproduce, with my edit more than five minutes after proposer's, so that's out.

As to my third review, I "know" I did it, but I can't prove it, so I'll leave that for now and pay extra attention whilst reviewing.

Comment: Like you, I believe--but cannot confirm--that edit-collision glitches for my edits have been increasing recently.

Comment: Might be "If only the tags have been edited, the latest post body is displayed". Could be [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @Dukeling But showing text that wasn't there when the Review was done is confusing, isn't it? I don't follow the rationale if it bydesign, but maybe it is how it has to work for some reason?

Comment: I don't really think it *should* have been designed to work that way, just saying that it *could* have been, for some reason or another. Perhaps I should stop speculating on how things might have been designed to work - it's not all that constructive.