# Suggested edit on question page was different than in the review queue

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I was on the question page for [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3494019) and saw that there was a pending suggested edit.

The edit suggested, amongst other things, to change

> the element visualizationId

into

> the element visualization-id

But when you go to the actual review, that change isn't there and my reject reason looks rather silly. What's going on?

Comment: *Maybe* tangentially related: [My edit shown as proposed edit after review when I look at review result](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209430/my-edit-shown-as-proposed-edit-after-review-when-i-look-at-review-result)

Comment: The five-minute grace window [strikes again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100003/no-warning-when-op-edits-question-during-the-five-minute-grace-period).